# org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1 - while insert into DB

Tags: hibernate, jpa

We are getting following error occupationally while insert (create) data on data base using hibernate (JPA) entity manager. We are not performing any other DB update or insert action on this flow.

Stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3070) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2949) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3329) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:560) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 129 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, this error is thrown when Hibernate tries to found an id which doesn't exist (already deleted)

Try to debug on hibernate log and see what is the last query executed and it generates this behavior

Comment: Same thing updating with a wrong id 

`row count from update = 0`